# Configure maven cargo plugin jetty container for static content

Tags: html, maven, jetty, cargo

I need to configure jetty running from the maven cargo plugin to point it at static content, Ive looked through the jetty documentation and I cant see how to apply the configuration to jetty when it is running as part of cargo. I want to configure the webApp section and set the resource base as my angular app built as a module of this build:

```
 <execution>
                  <id>start jetty - angular webapp</id>
                  <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>start</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>                           
                        <container>
                            <containerId>jetty7x</containerId>
                            <type>embedded</type>
                        </container>
                        <webApp>
                            <resourceBases>
                                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                                <resourceBase>../calculator-web/dist</resourceBase>
                            </resourceBases>
                        </webApp>   
                        <configuration> 
                            <properties>                    
                                <cargo.servlet.port>11000</cargo.servlet.port>                                          
                            </properties>                               
                        </configuration>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Jetty starts but it seems to ignore this configuration and I just get a 404 for my index.html file.

Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Although cargo does not seem to support Jetty's *reload* or *automatic hot redeploy* feature directly, at least you can serve your 'unfinished' static content and immediately pick up changes, e.g. during development while running an embedded container.

My current solution is to reconfigure [Jetty's `DefaultServlet`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/advanced-extras.html#default-servlet), pointing the `resourceBase` to the project's 'live' source directory (e.g. `${basedir}/src/main/webapp`) rather than the deployable's [default (build) `<location/>`](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide.html) (e.g. `${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}`), and (just to be sure) [disabling `useFileMappedBuffer`](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/troubleshooting-locked-files-on-windows.html) to avoid file locking in Windows:

1. Copy Jetty's [`webdefault.xml`](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/webdefault-xml.html) (from e.g. `target/cargo/configurations/jetty.../etc/` when running the cargo container as standalone) to, for instance, `src/main/jetty/my-webdefault.xml`
2. Modify its `DefaultServlet` initialization parameters:

   ```
   <web-app ...> <!-- src/main/jetty/my-webdefault.xml -->
     :
     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
       :
       <init-param> <!-- relative to pom.xml, or wherever cargo runs -->
         <param-name>resourceBase</param-name>
         <param-value>./src/main/webapp</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param> <!-- to avoid file locking in Windows, use: false -->
         <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
       </init-param>
     </servlet>
   </web-app>
   ```
3. Have the `cargo-maven2-plugin` [copy the new config file](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Configuration+files+option.html) `my-webdefault.xml` into the (Jetty) container's `etc/` directory:

   ```
   <project ...> <!-- pom.xml -->
     :
     <build>
       :
       <plugins>
         :
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
           <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>...</version>
           <configuration>
             <container>...</container>
             <configuration>
               <configfiles>
                 <configfile>
                   <file>${basedir}/src/main/jetty/my-webdefault.xml</file>
                   <tofile>etc/webdefault.xml</tofile>
                 </configfile>
               </configfiles>
               <properties>...</properties>
             </configuration>
             <deployables>...</deployables>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
   </project>
   ```
4. Run with `mvn clean verify cargo:run`

PS. My attempts with a `scratch.xml` to trigger a simple [static content `ResourceHandler`](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/static-content-deployment.html) in a separate context (e.g. `/static`) were without success.